# Делегирование свойств в C#

Tags: c#

Допустим, есть класс с неким свойством:

```
class C {
    public int property { set; get; }
}
```

Хочу в другом классе прокинуть это свойство через член класса. Очевидное решение такое:

```
class D {
    private C c = new C();
    public int property {
         set { c.property = value; }
         get { return c.property; }
    }
}
```

Есть ли какой-то упрощенный синтаксис для этого?

Условно:

```
public int property => c;
```

Может быть даже с возможностью менять уровень доступа, как это сделано для свойств по умолчанию (без явного поля для хранения состояния).

Comment: в смысле, вам нужен декоратор класса или просо делегирование конкретного свойства?

Comment: ну и есть же упроженный синтаксис, типа `set => c.property = value;  get => c.property;`

Comment: @tym32167 оформите ответом, пожалуйста, если есть такой синтаксис и с какой версии он появился.

Comment: Напишите себе сниппет и пользуйтесь

Comment: @АндрейNOP можно чуть поподробнее?

Comment: @alexout, ну про сниппеты знаете же? В Visual Studio, например, наберите `propfull` и нажмите 2 раза Tab, появится шаблон для свойства, в котором достаточно ввести только изменяемые части (переход между ними по Tab). Вот можно создать такой же сниппет для делегирующего свойства.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такого делегирования нет.

1. Если нужно вытащить *все* свойства вложенного объекта, то у вас два пути:

   1. Предоставить доступ к вложенному объекту напрямую через свойство. Контроль вы теряете, зато код будет чистым.
   2. Унаследоваться от вложенного объекта. Часто это совершенно некорректно (следите за соблюдением отношения is-a), но с точки зрения языка вы получаете требуемое поведение. Контроля нет, архитектура сомнительная, зато сато самый краткий вариант.
2. Если нужно вытащить *некоторые* свойства, при этом всё остальное важно скрыть, то есть следующие варианты:

   1. Не полениться и сделать всё вручную. Упрощённый синтаксис из C# 7 вам уже подсказали. Этот подход даёт максимальный контроль над безопасностью и архитектурой, но этот вариант самый многословный.
   2. Выделить необходимые свойства в интерфейс, реализовать его во вложенном объекте, предоставить наружу объект в виде интерфейса. Контроль достаточный (можно привести тип, но это уже на совести приводящего), архитектура и синтаксис разумные, чистота кода средненькая. Самый компромиссный вариант. Из минусов — требуется доступ к классу вложенного объекта, потому что extension everything до сих пор нет.

Comment: Почему C#7, если всё же 6?

Comment: @alexolut В C# 6 лямбдоморфировать можно только методы и свойства, в C# 7 — геттеры, конструкторы и прочее.

Comment: Для пункта 2, кстати, в студии есть автоматика "Implement interface through 'A'"

Comment: @АндрейNOP А это точно в студии, а не в решарпере?

Comment: В студии, у меня решарпера-то и нет

Answer (score 2):

Класс можно написать вот так

```
class D
{
    private C c = new C();
    public int property
    {
        set => c.property = value;  
        get => c.property;
    }
}
```

Вот такие выражения `set => c.property = value;` называются [Expression-bodied function members](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#expression-bodied-function-members) и появились в C# 6 версии.

Comment: Как-то это не выглядит упрощением, если честно. Конечно, чуть поменьше, чем в явном варианте, но всё же более лаконичный вариант кажется имел бы шанс на существование.

Comment: @alexolut ну, если вам прямо нужен декоратор, то вы всегда можете обратиться к перехватчикам из IoC контейнеров или к AOP (например, [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/)), но это только если хочется таое делать в промышленных масштабах. А для 1 свойства и так сойдет :)